# escape utf8 decoding ('\x74' to 't')

Tags: python, utf-8

I have this string `"\x00\x12\xf8\x05\x74\xa2"`, and following result:

```
>>> s = "\x00\x12\xf8\x05\x74\xa2"
>>> s
'\x00\x12\xf8\x05t\xa2'
>>> print s
?t?
>>> print repr(s)
'\x00\x12\xf8\x05t\xa2'


>>> s = r"\x00\x12\xf8\x05\x74\xa2" <=== (I want this result but cannot use r'')
>>> s
'\\x00\\x12\\xf8\\x05\\x74\\xa2'
>>> print s
\x00\x12\xf8\x05\x74\xa2
```

You could see that the `'\x74'` in the string is converted into the corresponding utf8 character `'t'` automatically in the first half output. I actually have a customized dictionary to do the decoding so I do not want this auto conversion.

It would be best if I could keep the string same as `r'string'` in the second half output. Clearly `repr` does not work, is there any other way to do it?

**UPDATE: I want this because I need to convert `hh` in every `\xhh` into int number.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by this?

Comment: if your intent is to use the string byte by byte then it shouldn't matter how it gets echoed back to you, it'll have the same internal representation.  If you want to go through the characters you're seeing without using `r` then you need to escape each backslash manually

Comment: @Daenyth I need to map every hex `hh` in the `\xhh` to int. use `int('\xhh', 16) could not work.

Comment: @xhainingx actually I want to extract `hh` in every `\xhh` so that I could convert them into int.

Comment: @Yulong like this? `>>> [ord(x) for x in list(s)]
[0, 18, 248, 5, 116, 162]`

Comment: you'd probably be better off using `0xhh` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> UPDATE: I want this because I need to convert hh in every \xhh into
>   int number.

```
>>> s = "\x00\x12\xf8\x05\x74\xa2"
>>> [ord(x) for x in list(s)]
[0, 18, 248, 5, 116, 162]
```

Comment: Ah, the power of asking for what you really want instead of what you think you want. Of course now the answer doesn't match the title of the question at all.

Comment: @MarkRansom sorry for the confusion. Next time I will surly stick with the title.

Answer (score 3):

> I want this because I need to convert hh in every \xhh into int
>   number.

```
In [17]: s = "\x00\x12\xf8\x05\x74\xa2"

In [18]: list(bytearray(s))
Out[18]: [0, 18, 248, 5, 116, 162]
```

[This article](http://dabeaz.blogspot.com/2010/01/few-useful-bytearray-tricks.html) on uses for bytearrays may be of interest to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually create your desired representation like this:

```
>>> s = '\x00\x12\xf8\x05\x74\xa2'
>>> r = ''.join(['\\x%02x' % ord(b) for b in s])
>>> r
'\\x00\\x12\\xf8\\x05\\x74\\xa2'
>>> print r
\x00\x12\xf8\x05\x74\xa2
```

Per your update, if you just want the `ord` values, rip out a small piece of my original answer:

```
>>> [ord(b) for b in s]
[0, 18, 248, 5, 116, 162]
```